# How to fix the location of my Linechart's crosshair

Tags: java, javafx, charts, line, linechart

So, I succeed to implement your code and change it to call a class Cursor. Here is the code of the Cursor and how I call it in my main controller. Thus, I decided to make a cursor as a parameter for my chart. And when i press a button which creates a cursor. But it's not the best way to do it i think , I would like to call a function createCursor which add line to a chart but it's not possible to add line to chart's children

```
public class Curseur<X, Y>  {

private Line vLine ;
private Line hLine ;
private boolean estUtilisé = false;


public Curseur(Line vLine, Line hLine, boolean estUtilise) {

    this.estUtilisé = estUtilisé;
    this.vLine = vLine;
    this.hLine = hLine;

}



public boolean isEstUtilisé() {
    return estUtilisé;
}

  public void moveCrossHair(double x, double y) {
      vLine.setStartX(x);
      hLine.setStartY(y);
  }



public void setEstUtilisé(boolean estUtilisé) {
    this.estUtilisé = estUtilisé;
}



public Line getvLine() {
    return vLine;
}

public void setvLine(Line vLine) {
    this.vLine = vLine;
}

public Line gethLine() {
    return hLine;
}

public void sethLine(Line hLine) {
    this.hLine = hLine;
}



    Line vLine = new Line();
    Line hLine = new Line();
    boolean used = false;
    Curseur curseur = new Curseur(vLine, hLine, used);

    final CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = 




   new CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis, curseur);

    XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("Super");
    updateSeriesData(series1);

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("Rate");
    updateSeriesData(series2);

    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3.setName("Stock");
    updateSeriesData(series3);

    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    lineChart.prefHeightProperty().bind(chartTemplate.heightProperty());
    lineChart.prefWidthProperty().bind(chartTemplate.widthProperty());
    chartTemplate.getChildren().add(lineChart);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114406/javafx-circle-must-follow-cursor

Comment: In the event filter, you should start the loop when the mouse enters the pane with the chart. You should stop the loop when the mouse exits the pane with the chart. You may have to create a smaller project that has a couple of charts and duplicates your exact problem.  When I ran the code from the original post, the crosshairs where close to the mouse location.

Comment: @Sedrick Hi, i'll try what you said but i think that it worked well because you tried it in a launch application? For exemple, my application is a group of graph, a graph is situated on a Pane, StackPane or a BorderPane, don't you think it plays a role to my cursor following my mouse with a big distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think that the crosshair should be within the bounds of plot area. I can see that the lines come over labels and legend. So gave a try to handle this feature internally so that it can be reused.

Below is a quick demo of my approach. The idea is to create a custom LineChart and add the lines to the plot area and move them as per the mouse movements.

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class LineChart_Crosshair_Demo extends Application {

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        yAxis.setLabel("Data");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("Super");
        updateSeriesData(series1);

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("Rate");
        updateSeriesData(series2);

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("Stock");
        updateSeriesData(series3);

        Line vLine = new Line();
        Line hLine = new Line();
        Curseur curseur = new Curseur(vLine, hLine, true);

        final CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new CrossHairLineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis, curseur);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

        CheckBox showCrosshairCB = new CheckBox("Show Crosshair");
        showCrosshairCB.setSelected(curseur.isEstUtilisé());
        showCrosshairCB.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, show) -> curseur.setEstUtilisé(show));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(showCrosshairCB);
        borderPane.setCenter(lineChart);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void updateSeriesData(XYChart.Series series) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i = (i + 2)) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, rnd.nextInt(50)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class Curseur {
        private Line vLine;
        private Line hLine;
        private BooleanProperty estUtilisé = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public Curseur(Line vLine, Line hLine, boolean estUtilisé) {
            this.vLine = vLine;
            this.hLine = hLine;
            this.estUtilisé.set(estUtilisé);
        }

        public Line getvLine() {
            return vLine;
        }

        public Line gethLine() {
            return hLine;
        }

        public boolean isEstUtilisé() {
            return estUtilisé.get();
        }

        public void setEstUtilisé(boolean estUtilisé) {
            this.estUtilisé.set(estUtilisé);
        }

        public BooleanProperty estUtiliséProperty() {
            return estUtilisé;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom line chart to include cross hair on plot area.
     *
     * @param <X>
     * @param <Y>
     */
    private class CrossHairLineChart<X, Y> extends LineChart {

        private Line vLine;
        private Line hLine;
        private Group plotArea;
        private BooleanProperty showFlag = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private BooleanProperty showCrossHair = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private double tickSize = 5;

        public CrossHairLineChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis, Curseur curseur) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
            vLine = curseur.getvLine();
            hLine = curseur.gethLine();
            showCrossHair.set(curseur.isEstUtilisé());
            curseur.estUtiliséProperty().addListener((obs, old, show) -> showCrossHair.set(show));

            hLine.endYProperty().bind(hLine.startYProperty());
            vLine.endXProperty().bind(vLine.startXProperty());
            vLine.visibleProperty().bind(showFlag);
            hLine.visibleProperty().bind(showFlag);
            setOnMouseExited(e -> showFlag.set(false));
            setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
                if (isShowCrossHair() && plotArea != null) {
                    Bounds b = plotArea.getBoundsInLocal();
                    // If the mouse cursor is within the plot area bounds
                    if (b.getMinX() < e.getX() && e.getX() < b.getMaxX() && b.getMinY() < e.getY() && e.getY() < b.getMaxY()) {
                        showFlag.set(true);
                        moveCrossHair(e.getX() - b.getMinX() - tickSize, e.getY() - b.getMinY() - tickSize);
                    } else {
                        showFlag.set(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void moveCrossHair(double x, double y) {
            vLine.setStartX(x);
            hLine.setStartY(y);
        }

        public boolean isShowCrossHair() {
            return showCrossHair.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty showCrossHairProperty() {
            return showCrossHair;
        }

        public void setShowCrossHair(boolean showCrossHair) {
            this.showCrossHair.set(showCrossHair);
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
            super.layoutPlotChildren();
            if (plotArea == null && !getPlotChildren().isEmpty()) {
                Group plotContent = (Group) ((Node) getPlotChildren().get(0)).getParent();
                plotArea = (Group) plotContent.getParent();
            }
            if (!getPlotChildren().contains(vLine)) {
                getPlotChildren().addAll(vLine, hLine);
            }
            hLine.setStartX(0);
            hLine.setEndX(getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());

            vLine.setStartY(0);
            vLine.setEndY(getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update 2 [Multiple charts & Freezing]**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class MultipleLineChart_Crosshair_Demo extends Application {

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Curseur curseur = new Curseur(-1, -1, true);

        CheckBox showCrosshairCB = new CheckBox("Show Crosshair");
        showCrosshairCB.setSelected(curseur.isEstUtilisé());
        showCrosshairCB.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, show) -> curseur.setEstUtilisé(show));

        CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number> lineChart1 = buildChart();
        lineChart1.setCursor(curseur);

        CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number> lineChart2 = buildChart();
        lineChart2.setCursor(curseur);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(showCrosshairCB);
        borderPane.setCenter(new VBox(lineChart1, lineChart2));
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number> buildChart() {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        yAxis.setLabel("Data");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("Super");
        updateSeriesData(series1);

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("Rate");
        updateSeriesData(series2);

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("Stock");
        updateSeriesData(series3);

        final CrossHairLineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new CrossHairLineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        return lineChart;
    }

    private void updateSeriesData(XYChart.Series series) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i = (i + 2)) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, rnd.nextInt(50)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class Curseur {
        private DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        private DoubleProperty y = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        private BooleanProperty estUtilisé = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private BooleanProperty showing = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private BooleanProperty freeze = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public Curseur(double x, double y, boolean estUtilisé) {
            setX(x);
            setY(y);
            this.estUtilisé.set(estUtilisé);
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x.get();
        }

        public DoubleProperty xProperty() {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(double x) {
            this.x.set(x);
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y.get();
        }

        public DoubleProperty yProperty() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(double y) {
            this.y.set(y);
        }

        public boolean isEstUtilisé() {
            return estUtilisé.get();
        }

        public void setEstUtilisé(boolean estUtilisé) {
            this.estUtilisé.set(estUtilisé);
        }

        public BooleanProperty estUtiliséProperty() {
            return estUtilisé;
        }

        public boolean isShowing() {
            return showing.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty showingProperty() {
            return showing;
        }

        public void setShowing(boolean showing) {
            this.showing.set(showing);
        }

        public boolean isFreeze() {
            return freeze.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty freezeProperty() {
            return freeze;
        }

        public void setFreeze(boolean freeze) {
            this.freeze.set(freeze);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Custom line chart to include cross hair on plot area.
     *
     * @param <X>
     * @param <Y>
     */
    private class CrossHairLineChart<X, Y> extends LineChart {

        private Line vLine;
        private Line hLine;
        private Group plotArea;
        private BooleanProperty showFlag = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private BooleanProperty showCrossHair = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private BooleanProperty freeze = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        private double tickSize = 5;
        private Curseur cursor;

        public CrossHairLineChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
            vLine = new Line();
            hLine = new Line();

            hLine.endYProperty().bind(hLine.startYProperty());
            vLine.endXProperty().bind(vLine.startXProperty());
            vLine.visibleProperty().bind(showFlag.or(freeze));
            hLine.visibleProperty().bind(showFlag.or(freeze));
            setOnMouseExited(e -> {
                if (isShowCrossHair() && !isFreeze()) {
                    showFlag.set(false);
                }
            });
            setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
                if (isShowCrossHair() && plotArea != null && !isFreeze()) {
                    // If the mouse cursor is within the plot area bounds
                    if (isWithinPlotArea(e)) {
                        showFlag.set(true);
                        moveCrossHair(e);
                    } else {
                        showFlag.set(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (isShowCrossHair() && isWithinPlotArea(e)) {
                    freeze.set(!isFreeze());
                    if (!isFreeze()) {
                        moveCrossHair(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private boolean isWithinPlotArea(MouseEvent e) {
            Bounds b = plotArea.getBoundsInLocal();
            return b.getMinX() < e.getX() && e.getX() < b.getMaxX() && b.getMinY() < e.getY() && e.getY() < b.getMaxY();
        }

        public void setCursor(Curseur cursor) {
            this.cursor = cursor;
            showCrossHair.set(cursor.isEstUtilisé());
            cursor.estUtiliséProperty().addListener((obs, old, show) -> showCrossHair.set(show));
            cursor.xProperty().addListener((obs, old, xVal) -> vLine.setStartX(xVal.doubleValue()));
            cursor.yProperty().addListener((obs, old, yVal) -> hLine.setStartY(yVal.doubleValue()));
            showFlag.bindBidirectional(cursor.showingProperty());
            freeze.bindBidirectional(cursor.freezeProperty());
        }

        private void moveCrossHair(MouseEvent e) {
            Bounds b = plotArea.getBoundsInLocal();
            double x = e.getX() - b.getMinX() - tickSize;
            double y = e.getY() - b.getMinY() - tickSize;

            vLine.setStartX(x);
            hLine.setStartY(y);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.setX(x);
                cursor.setY(y);
            }
        }

        public boolean isShowCrossHair() {
            return showCrossHair.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty showCrossHairProperty() {
            return showCrossHair;
        }

        public void setShowCrossHair(boolean showCrossHair) {
            this.showCrossHair.set(showCrossHair);
        }

        public boolean isFreeze() {
            return freeze.get();
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
            super.layoutPlotChildren();
            if (plotArea == null && !getPlotChildren().isEmpty()) {
                Group plotContent = (Group) ((Node) getPlotChildren().get(0)).getParent();
                plotArea = (Group) plotContent.getParent();
            }
            if (!getPlotChildren().contains(vLine)) {
                getPlotChildren().addAll(vLine, hLine);
            }
            hLine.setStartX(0);
            hLine.setEndX(getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());

            vLine.setStartY(0);
            vLine.setEndY(getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, your answer is very helpful for me thank you. I succeed to implement it in my app, but now I would like to have the chart without cursor at the beginning, but when we press a button it creates a cursor on the graph. Do you think thats possible?

Comment: Very nice implementation.

Comment: @Floxii, I updated my demo code to include the show cursor dynamically.

Comment: @SaiDandem really thank you thats exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @SaiDandem I'm sorry to come again, but I'm facing a problem, Ideally, the cursor is an Object. I want to be able to call a method addCursor which will create a cursor. So i tried, but when I try to remove the lines of the construtor to build these lines from an other class, the cursor will not follow my mouse as it could : https://imgur.com/a/YwV4iCb

Comment: Can you provide the code sample of how you are adding the cursor.

Comment: @Floxii, I updated my demo code to include the Curseur in line chart.

Comment: @SaiDandem perfect, but I was wondering myself if it was very optimized to include a Cursor directly in the chart and to "hide" it since we didn't tick the checkbox?

Comment: @Floxii, I am not sure about your requirement, but if you say that you want to set the cursor from an external object, and you want to still controll its visibility only through Curseur object, then i think you need to modify the estUtilisé as on observable property. Updated my code to control the visibility through Curseur object. But still allowed the flexibility to change the visibility through an API in chart.

Comment: @SaiDandem That's barely what I want to do. In fact, I'm wondering if having a cursor in Chart's constructor is a good way to program it. Like I think that a function "addCursor" in the chart class would be more efficient?

Comment: @Floxii, in general I would let the feature of crosshair as a built in feature of chart and enable/disable it through property setter. I dont know the exact reason why do you want to pass it as a Cursor. What are the primary reasons that you want to pass it externally to the chart?

Comment: @SaiDandem I want to pass threw a Cursor because i'll need different chart to have the "same cursor'. In fact, axis' graphes will be connecter so when one will move, the other one's axis will need to move with it

Comment: @SaiDandem Moreover,  would you know how can I do to make the cursor stop when I click on a data or on the graph, then if I click again it would unlock the cursor

Comment: Regarding the question of using same cursor, i think you cannot do that. Because in scenegraph once a node is rendered you cannot render it again in another place. May be for this you need to have Cursor with just the coorninates (not Lines) and control it in multiple charts.

Comment: @SaiDandem Well, i'm currently trying to find a way to do it, replacing lines by axis could be a good idea!

Comment: @Floxii, once you tried your own approach please give a look to my approach. I updated a new demo code separately for handling all the functionality of Toggling & Multiple charts & Freezing in one demo. I strongly suggest you to first give a try from your side and then refer to mine. Please note that there may be some code improvements, my main aim is to give you some conceptual idea of how to solve this issue/requirment. :)

Comment: @SaiDandem wow that's awsome. I just launched it and it works very well !! The only problem I found was that if the 2 charts are not doing the same height/width the cursor may have some issues to follow the other one. Im currently working on it :)